# Hide/Unhide some rows according a list value

Tags: vba, excel, hide

I'm trying to hide/unhide some rows according a list value and if they are hidden set a cell to 0. The code is hidding the rows if I select 1 but it won't unhide them if I select any other value. The values I have available are 1 to 5.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Updated by Extendoffice 20180822
    If Target.Address = "$F$16" Then
        If Target.Value <= 2 Then
            Application.Rows("22:25").Select
            Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("F22").Value = "0"
            Range("F23").Value = "0"
            Range("F24").Value = "0"
            Range("F25").Value = "0"
        ElseIf Target.Value <= 3 Then
            Application.Rows("23:25").Select
            Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("F23").Value = "0"
            Range("F24").Value = "0"
            Range("F25").Value = "0"
        ElseIf Target.Value <= 4 Then
            Application.Rows("24:25").Select
            Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("F24").Value = "0"
            Range("F25").Value = "0"
        ElseIf Target.Value <= 5 Then
            Application.Rows("25:25").Select
            Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("F25").Value = "0"
        ElseIf Target.Value <= 6 Then
            Application.Rows("22:25").Select
            Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By selecting 1, you are hitting the first IF statement and hiding 22:25. By trying to change the value, won't do anything because "ElseIf Target.Value <= 6 Then" will never get executed, because every value is <= 6. You need to "reset" your values when the event is fired -> add this to the top of the Sub prior to the If Thens...

> ```
> If Target.Address = "$F$16" Then
>         Application.Rows("22:25").Select
>         Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
>         Range("F22").Value = "[whatever default value should be]"
>         Range("F23").Value = "[whatever default value should be]"
>         Range("F24").Value = "[whatever default value should be]"
>         Range("F25").Value = "[whatever default value should be]"
> ```

Comment: Could be shortened to `Rows("22:25").Hidden=false`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code only says to hide rows under a certain condition, it doesn't say to show them under others except where the cell = 6, but the logic would never get that far because any value from 1-5 would meet the first 5 conditions and then exit the `if` statement.

If you want to flip the `hidden` boolean (the true/false value) back and forth, you could dim a boolean variable as not itself and then set the hidden property to that value:

```
Dim TorF as Boolean
TorF = Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden 'to set the boolean's value

Application.Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = Not TorF 'to flip it
```